# install.bat file not working for dataloader version 57.0.0 spring'23 windows

Tags: data-loader, dataloader-batch

I tried to install the data loader for my windows 10 (64 bit) system but the install.bat file not working.

I have installed the zulu11.62.17-ca-jdk11.0.18-win_x64 and even i have setup the java home variable also on during the installation.

After the installation of zulu 11, I have extract the data loader new version 57.0 zip file and i tried to install the dataloader by using the install.bat file with double click.

**But there is no any response i get and the data loader install CMD prompt was not opened**. For this reason i can't moved to next step.

anyone please help me to resolve this issue and please guide me how to go for the next step.

**Note : I tried the same installation with zulu 18 also, but i faced this same issue**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the install.bat file from an open CMD?

1. start cmd under the user (no administrator privileges required)
2. navigate in cmd to where the install.bat file (and the other Data Loader files are located)
3. type: .\install.bat
   then the installer should start